# Object won't highlight in the 3d viewport

Tags: modeling

This was working fine until I exited blender without saving my file.  When I restarted blender 2.8 and opened my file when I click on an object it highlights in the Scene Collection but not in the 3d Viewport. I am able to manipulate them but I need to see what I have selected.

Jerry

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe you deactivated the Outline in the Viewport Overlay? In Object Mode, click the arrow next to the Overlay button (top right) and make sure the box is checked.

Comment: To go along with this, make sure that the viewport overlay is enabled. Make sure that the button by the dropdown is blue, as it is in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.